# Why I can't delete everything except for certain characters using a loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a code

```
def printer_error(s):
    allowed = "abcdefghijklm"
    return [s.replace(x, "") for x in allowed if x in s]
print(printer_error("xyzabcdef"))
```

That is what code must returns:

```
"abcdef"
```

And that is what code returns really:

```
['xyzbcdef', 'xyzacdef', 'xyzabdef', 'xyzabcef', 'xyzabcdf', 'xyzabcde']
```

I think that the problem is on line 3, but idk what`s wrong

Comment: If you want to return a string, why are you using a list comprehension? List comprehensions are for creating lists.

Comment: Its because you're using a list comprehension, instead you just have to have that `replace` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because you're using a list comprehension, instead you just have to have that `replace` function, like this...

```py
def printer_error(s):
    allowed = "abcdefghijklm"

    for char in s:
        if char not in allowed:
            s = s.replace(char, "")

    return s
print(printer_error("xyzabcdef"))
```

Comment: it's not necessary to check whether x is in s

Comment: It is, for you can't replace the letters that are not in `allowed`

Comment: Your code returns `xyzabcdef` (not what OP wants, but that's another issue). If you remove the line `if x in s:` and fix the indentation of the next line, the output is again `xyzabcdef`.

Comment: There are two issues - `str.replace()` does not work inplace, i.e. you need s=s.replace() and second - this will remove chars in allowed, and OP claims they want `"abcdef"`

Comment: Really don't know how this could be the accepted answer, given the expected output `"abcdef"`

Comment: Now, that's something completely different...

Comment: Listen!!! my main motive was to pin-point the `list comprehension` was unnecessary, and that instead of it just the `s.replace()` was to be there and he/she got it, it was not to produce the correct output.

Comment: @buran You are right. His answer had a lot of mistakes and the output was wrong. It's a kind of fraud. Because he/she copied the right answer from my answer and ...

Comment: There was problem with your answer before you fix all the other problems also present in OP question. So don't get mad when you are corrected.

Comment: I'm not mad at you, I just wanted to state my motive, since you started letting out all the errors in my code like a compiler :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def printer_error(s):
    allowed = "abcdefghijklm"
    for x in s:
        if x not in allowed:
            s = s.replace(x, "")
    return s
print(printer_error("xyzabcdef"))
```